# How to translate a PostGIS query to MySQL spatial query

Tags: mysql, postgis, mysql-spatial

I need to translate this PostGIS query:

```
SELECT boundary
        ST_Intersects(ST_SetSRID(ST_Buffer(ST_MakePoint(11.255492,43.779251),0.002), 4326), ST_GeomFromKML(boundary)) as intersect,
FROM 
    mytable 
WHERE 
        ST_Intersects(ST_SetSRID(ST_Buffer( ST_MakePoint(11.255492,43.779251),0.002), 4326), ST_GeomFromKML(boundary))
LIMIT 1
```

to MySQL with spatial data.

I tried this, but it is not working:

```
SELECT 
    boundary, 
    ST_Intersects(Buffer('POINT(11.7094335,44.2754631)', 2), GeomFromText(boundary)) as intersect
FROM 
    mytable 
WHERE 
    ST_Intersects(Buffer('POINT(11.7094335,44.2754631)', 2), GeomFromText(boundary))
```

The MySQL `boundary` column contains data in this format:

`POLYGON((11.752094222227 44.322710250414,11.753712975677 44.322710250414,11.753712975677 44.321900873689,11.752094222227 44.321900873689,11.752094222227 44.322710250414))`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's the error message you're getting?

Comment: I was not getting any error message. I solved the problem and I'm going to post the answer right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer by trying and trying again...
This solved the problem:

```
SELECT 
        boundary, 
        ST_Intersects(GEOMFROMTEXT(boundary), ST_Buffer(POINT(11.752094222227, 44.322710250414), 2)) as intersect
FROM 
        mytable 
WHERE  
        ST_Intersects(GEOMFROMTEXT(boundary), ST_Buffer(POINT(11.752094222227, 44.322710250414), 2))
```

I hope this could be useful for future users.